# very basic object prototype not sure why isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why this isn't working..

```
function Employee(vacation, takenAlready) {
  this.vacation_days_per_year = vacation;
  this.vacation_days_taken = takenAlready;
}

Employee.prototype.sally = function(){return this.vacation_days_per_year - this.vacation_days_taken};

console.log(sally(20, 5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you never actually create an `Employee` instance.  All you did was create a "class" and give it a few properties, one being a function named `sally`.

You need to use `new Employee` to create an object instance, then you can call its `sally` method.

```
var joe = new Employee(20, 5);
console.log(joe.sally());
```

Though, I don't think you really wanted to name the method `sally`, you probably wanted the object to be called that.  This is probably what you wanted:

```
function Employee(vacation, takenAlready) {
  this.vacation_days_per_year = vacation;
  this.vacation_days_taken = takenAlready;
}

Employee.prototype.vacation_days_left = function(){
    return this.vacation_days_per_year - this.vacation_days_taken
};

var sally = new Employee(20, 5);
console.log(sally.vacation_days_left());
```